# Run action/download-artifact@v2 unable to find any artifact for the associated workflow

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Run action/download-artifact@v2 unable to find any artifact for the associated workflow is failing.

**main_xxx.yml**

```yaml
Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy WAR app to Azure Web App - xxx

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean install

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: java-app
          path: '${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.war'

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: java-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'xxx'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.xxxxxx }}
          package: '*.war'
```

Comment: Please provide more details on your requirement and the errors if you are getting any.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce your requirement in my environment and got the same error during deployment:***

[image]

- I figured out that this error was thrown because the GitHub workflow was expecting for `JAR` file instead of `WAR`. I modified `JAR` to `WAR` in workflow and it worked.
- Make sure you have proper war configuration in `pom.xml`.
- Make sure you are using ***compatible version of JAVA***.

---

- Created a *spring-boot application with war packaging* and it's working fine.

**My `pom.xml` :**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>javawarproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>javawarproject</name>
    <description>javawarproject</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**GitHub Workflow to deploy War Spring boot application:**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy WAR app to Azure Web App - <web_app_name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean install

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: java-app
          path: '${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.war'

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: java-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: '<web_app_name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_6FAXXXXXXXX }}
          package: '*.war'
```

**Deployed the application successfully:**

[image]

**Deployed files can be seen in KUDU site=> Site wwwroot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This does not apply to the actual problem but is related to the error in the subject. You need to make sure you are using the same versions of the actions.

In other words, if you are using actions/upload-artifact@v4, you need to use actions/download-artifact@v4.